# I want to display tomorrows date following a given date

Tags: java, date, if-statement, calendar

I want to display tomorrow's date following a given date ( month date year)
I have no experience of programming but I'm trying to get used to doing this. I coded this but it's not even working and I am stuck on this. Can anyone take a look?

```
int Year, Month, Day;
int tYear, tMonth, tDay;

System.out.print("Enter the month [1 to 12]: ");
System.out.print("Enter the day of the month [1 to 31]: ");
System.out.print("Enter the year: ");

tDay = Day + 1;
tMonth = Month;
tYear = Year;

if (Month == 1 || Month == 3 || Month == 5 || Month == 7 || Month == 8 || Month == 10 || Month == 12) {

    if (tDay > 31) {
        tMonth = Month + 1;
        tDay = 1;
    }
} else if (Month == 4 || Month == 6 || Month == 9 || Month == 11) {

    if (tDay > 30) {
        tMonth = Month + 1;
        tDay = 1;
    }
} else {

    if ((Year % 4 == 0) && (!(Year % 100 == 0) || (Year % 400) == 0)) {

        if (tDay > 29) {
            tMonth = 3;
            tDay = 1;
        }
    } else {
        if (tDay > 28) {
            tMonth = 3;
            tDay = 1;
        }
    }
}

if (tMonth == 13) {
    tMonth = 1;
    tYear = Year + 1;
}

System.out.println("Today's date is: " + Month +
    "/" + Day + "/" + Year + ".");
System.out.println("Tomorrow's date will be: " + tMonth +
    "/" + tDay + "/" + tYear + ".");
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Java Date API's? Are you using Java 8?

Comment: There are enough decent ways where you can set a date and do something like: addDays(1);
Check JodaTime, for instance

Comment: an example for how to use the java 8 date api (which will solve your problems) https://dzone.com/articles/deeper-look-java-8-date-and

Comment: when you say it doesn't event work, what do you *mean* by this - what input have you tried and what do you get as your output? Also, try adding debugging statements through the code at different steps to check it's following paths you expect (i.e. use `System.out.println()` to print values along the way..)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Calendar` class for this:

```
    int year, month, day;
    int tYear, tMonth, tDay;

    System.out.print("Enter the month [1 to 12]: ");
    System.out.print("Enter the day of the month [1 to 31]: ");
    System.out.print("Enter the year: ");

    // read values

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, day);

    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    tYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    tMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    tDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

    System.out.println("Today's date is: " + month +
            "/" + day + "/" + year + ".");
    System.out.println("Tomorrow's date will be: " + tMonth +
            "/" + tDay + "/" + tYear + ".");
```

Also I recommend you to use `DateFormat` for formatting or parsing `Date`:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    int year, month, day;

    System.out.print("Enter the month [1 to 12]: ");
    System.out.print("Enter the day of the month [1 to 31]: ");
    System.out.print("Enter the year: ");

    // read values

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, day);

    String today = format.format(calendar.getTime());

    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    String tomorrow = format.format(calendar.getTime());

    System.out.println("Today's date is: " + today + ".");
    System.out.println("Tomorrow's date will be: " + tomorrow + ".");
```

Comment: small minor correction the OP is after the input date + 1 *day*, so you need to fix your example code...

Comment: @Nim, Could you explain more detaled. I didn't catch, sorry

Comment: You current code is adding a  month... to the input day, the op wants to add 1 *day*

Answer (score 1):

I would use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for all of this. There is a [plusDays](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusDays(int)) function there

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015,9,20, 0, 0);
DateTime oneDayLater = dt.plusDays(1);
```

There is a DateTime [ctor](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime(long)) that allows you to pass in millis since 1970 that will allow you to easily use java's Calendar and Date classes with this.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

In Java 8 and later, the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework handles this task.

```
LocalDate dayAfter = LocalDate.of( 2012 , 3 , 4 ).plusDays( 1 );
```